# Is it better to make a get request once or multiple times?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

For example, every React component must display certain set of items from database. Would it be better to create routes for each type of items on backend and then make get requests from components that have to display those or one big request of all items and then the response would be placed in state and every component maps items it supposed to display. Which approach is better?

Comment: I'd imagine that you won't always retrieve _all_ items _all_ the time. You might retrieve the users on one screen, and another screen retrieve the products, for example. So just load what you need and no more. This will save a lot of database reads/joins, which can be expensive. Also, your internet may be fast, but many people have slow connections, so I'd say definitely separate endpoints for different types of items and only fetch what you need for that screen.

Comment: From a performance point of view, fewer requests to a database to accomplish your current task without retrieving data you won't actually use is usually better than making lots of individual requests to accomplish the same task.  But, that's not an absolute so it really depends upon your particular situation and code.